# Why My jQuery Accordion remove after a Button click?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, postback, accordion

I want to use jQuery Accordion in my ASP.NEt Appliacation and it works but if I click on a Button in the Accordion then my Accordion remove :( Here my Code and two pitures...

aspx:

```
<link href="App_Theme/mainStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripte/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripte/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="App_Theme/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion();

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="manager" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="update" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

    <div id="accordion">
            <h3><a href="#"><asp:Label ID="lblAbwesenheit" runat="server"/></a></h3>
            <div>
                 <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pn1" DefaultButton="btnAbwesenheitErzeugen">
                            <div id="Angaben" runat="server">

                            <table id="Angabentabelle" runat="server">

                                <tr>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="lblAbwesenheitBis" runat="server" /></td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtAbwesenheitBis" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:ImageButton Width="20px" Height="20px" ID="imgbtnAbwesenheitBis" runat="server" ToolTip="Abwesenheit bis..." ImageUrl="~/App_Theme/Calender.ico"  />
                                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="AbwesenheitBis" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAbwesenheitBis"
                                 Format="dd.MM.yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgbtnAbwesenheitBis"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                                </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="lblVertreter" runat="server" /></td>
                                <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtVertreter" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoComlete" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtVertreter" 
                                ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" ServicePath="" Enabled="true"
                                DelimiterCharacters="" UseContextKey="true" MinimumPrefixLength="1" ></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
                                (Suche nach Nachname)
                                </td>

                                </tr>
                            </table>

                                <asp:Button ID="btnAbwesenheitErzeugen" runat="server" Text="Erzeugen" OnClick="btnAbwesenheitErzeugen_Click" />
                                <br />
                            <br />

                            </div>

                            <HTMLEditor:Editor ID="htmlEditAbwesenheit" runat="server" Content="<% %>" />

                            </asp:Panel>
            </div>
            <h3><a href="#"><asp:Label ID="lblSignatur" runat="server" /></a></h3>
            <div>
               <HTMLEditor:Editor ID="htmlEditSignatur" runat="server" Content="<% %>" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

If I start my Page I see that:

[image]

and if I click on the Button then I see that...

[image]

Why My Accordion remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your accordion is inside of an updatepanel. When you post back, everything inside your updatepanel is removed from the DOM and readded. Hence, the DOM element that was the accordion is gone. You need to call:  $("#accordion").accordion(); after your postback.

one way you could do that is to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function SetupAccordion(){
        $("#accordion").accordion();
   }
   $(document).ready(function () {
     SetupAccordion();
     if (typeof Sys.WebForms != 'undefined') {
       Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(SetupAccordion);
     }
   });   
</script>
```